# Networking Issues

Tags: networking, wireless, internet

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 in my PC. Hoe can I connect to wifi?

Comment: How did you disable networking?

Comment: How exactly did you disable it ? through the drop down menu ?

Comment: IDK...but I restarted the OS and now its done...thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tip for the future. When you disable wifi or networking and graphical tools don't work, you can always user command-line tools in terminal. The terminal can be accessed by searching for the app (by clicking on the Ubuntu icon in the launch bar on the left of your screen)

[image]

or by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>. You will see a window open with something likes this:

`user@ubuntu: /home/username: $`

To restart networking you can do `sudo service network-manager restart` (if you are using Ubuntu 14.04 or earlier) or `sudo systemctl restart network-manager` (for mater versions)

To turn wifi on or off use `nmcli nm wifi off` and `nmcli nm wifi on`

Best of luck and enjoy Ubuntu !

Comment: This should also have details for the network manager GUI too - the OP seems unfamiliar with network manager.  Won't down vote but I strongly suggest including the standard GUI procedure too.